# How are u128 numbers stored in memory?

Tags: rust

I'm reconstructing `u128` numbers passed over the internet. My idea is to break the number down into `u8`s on one end of the connection, send those and rebuild the `u128` on the other end.

I attempted reconstructing a `u8` buffer by casting its pointer to `*const u8` to `*const u128`:

```rust
fn main() {
    let mut b = [0u8; 16];
    b[14] = 1;
    let addr = &b as *const u8 as *const u128;

    unsafe {
        println!("{:?}", &b as *const u8);
        println!("{:?}\n", b);

        println!("{:?}", addr);
        println!("n = {}", *addr);
    }
}
```

To my surprise, the generated output looked like this:

```
0x7efe2088
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]

0x7efe2088
n = 5192296858534827628530496329220096
```

I expected this array to contain

```
00000000 00000000 ... 00000001 00000000 = 256
```

Now I'm confused. Considering two different options as possibilities:

- The array is stored backwards, storing `b[14]` as the second byte;
- A `*const u128` (which points to `b[0]`) reads the allocated bytes backwards.

Which one of these is correct? Is there something I don't understand about the way Rust (or computers in general) store data?

Comment: [Endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness)

Comment: [`to_be_bytes`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.u128.html#method.to_be_bytes) and [`from_be_bytes`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.u128.html#method.from_be_bytes) are what you want.

Comment: The array is not stored backwards. You expected the most significant bytes to be stored first, which would be a "big-endian" architecture. Almost all architectures you're likely to encounter today are "little-endian", meaning they store least significant bytes first in memory, as you observed.  Note that the compiler - if it wants to emit efficient code - cannot choose the layout of the number in memory, it must use the representation chosen by the CPU.

Comment: @user4815162342 I've been trying to nail down if `u128` is *guaranteed* to be in a specific format, especially considering that most processors don't have general-purpose 128-bit registers. I don't know that there _is_ a representation chosen by the CPU! I'd certainly hope that it follows the native target endianness just for simplicity though...

Comment: Also worth noting that `u128`s do have an alignment greater than `u8`s do so your code does cause undefined behavior.

Comment: @Shepmaster That's a fair point - I assumed that on modern CPUs some form of 128-bit manipulation isntructions existed, even if there are no such registers. Failing that, LLVM's 128-bit intrinsics, if rustc uses them, might have endianness requirements. But even without either of those, the endianness of 64-bit chunks must be respected, given that the compiler [generates 64-bit instructions](https://godbolt.org/z/o9qcfsxGf) to manipulate u128. So the valid choices would be little-endian and a hybrid like the 128-bit analogue of [PDP endian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness#PDP-endian).

Comment: @Aiden4 Is that still the case if I send 16 `u8`s? That would be the same as a single `u128` right?

Comment: The alignment of the buffer is the problem, not how it's sent over the network. You need to force it to have the same alignment as a `u128` before converting it to a `u128`. The best way to do this would either writing a simple struct with an artificially raised alignment or by casting a buffer of `u128`s into a buffer of `u8`s.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your confusion stems from [endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness). This concept applies to computers in general, not just Rust. Some computer architectures are natively big-endian (e.g. [MIPS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIPS_architecture)), some are little endian (e.g. [x86](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86)), and some can be both (e.g. [ARM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARM_architecture))!.

For transporting the numbers over the internet, you should choose what order you want send them (either big-endian or little endian; big-endian is the traditional choice, though little-endian systems are more common these days), and then explicitly convert when sending and receiving. This way, your program will still work even if the two computers talking have a different endianness (for example, MIPS and x86-64 are different).

As [@loganfsmyth notes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68459341/how-are-u128-numbers-stored-in-memory#comment120989259_68459341), Rust has built-in methods to do this conversion from a `u128` to an array of `u8`s (and vice-versa), these methods are:

- [`to_be_bytes`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.u128.html#method.to_be_bytes)
- [`from_be_bytes`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.u128.html#method.from_be_bytes)
- [`to_le_bytes`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.u128.html#method.to_le_bytes)
- [`from_le_bytes`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.u128.html#method.from_le_bytes)

Comment: Amazing! Thank you for the clear explanation.